# How to connect another user id with my input for that user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Another user posts a problem, and I can click on that post to see details about that problem (not through show) and give a recommendation. The thing is that I don't want my recommendation to be linked with this problem. I want it to be linked with that user herself. To do this, I tried:

```rb
create
    @recommendation = current_user.recommendations.build(recommendation_params)
    @user = User.where(user: params[:user_id])
    @recommendation.helped_id = @user.id 
end
```

where helped_id should equate that user's id. (later I want that user to be able to see all recommendations she's been given)

But it's turning up error, saying

```
undefined method `id' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007ff6a9621f68> Did you mean? ids
```

UPDATE

So I go to the url where this other user's problem is detailed by this view code:

```rb
<% @users.each do |u| %>
<%= link_to new_recommendation_path(user_id: u.id) do %>
```

And the url is: http://localhost:3000/recommendations/new?user_id=2

Could this be the problem?

@user = User.find(params[:user_id]) works fine in new method for showing the problem, but the same code in create method returns cannot find.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `find` method which returns the object instead of a relation...

```
@user = User.find(params[:user_id])
```

Comment: Thank you. This returns Couldn't find User without an ID.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to continue using AR Relation, so your code would be

```
    @recommendation = current_user.recommendations.build(recommendation_params)
    @user = User.where(id: params[:user_id]).first
    @recommendation.helped_id = @user.id
```

Tip: In both scenarios, using User.find or User.where, you should take care of exceptional cases.

- Using User.find, if user doesn't exist, then an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound will be raised.
- Using User.where, if user doesn't exist, then a NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass) will be raised.

Comment: Thank you. I got this:```PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column users.user does not exist LINE 1: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."user" IS NULL ... ^ : SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."user" IS NULL ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1```

Comment: Oh i see, you are specifying user as parameter name on where method. I updated the answer to fix that

Comment: Thank you. I got the same error message. ```PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column users.user_id does not exist LINE 1: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."user_id" IS NU... ^ : SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."user_id" IS NULL ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1```

Comment: My bad superbot, if your application is following Rails convention then the name should be just id. I fixed one more time the answer.

Comment: Thank you! A new error pops up: ```undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass``` The primary key of User is "id."

Comment: In that case, you should check the params[:user_id] to see if is a valid primary key of User model. The database is not finding a User with the value provided by params[:user_id]

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add nested resources for user and recommendations

```rb
  resources :users, shallow: true do
    resources :recommendations
  end
```

And, in the view, pass both user and recommendation parameters to the recommendation page.

```rb
<% @users.each do |u| %>
<%= link_to new_user_recommendation_path(u.id, @recommendation) do %>
```

Then `@user = User.find(params[:user_id])` works.